# Not able to find JMSContext class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms, solace

How to solve below

> : Failed to introspect Class
> [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from
> ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2a139a55]
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
> ```

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.solace.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>solace-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to miss `javax-jms` dependency, try to add the following in case of you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes i figured it out .Thanks .Its resolved now.